# Alamofire 4 + Model return an empty value

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm still beginner in iOS development. I'm using Alamofire 4 and SwiftyJSON in order to fetch the data. When I debug, I noticed that its execute `return country_list` first, and then only go to Alamofire body. I have do some search but still not found the answer.

Model

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire

class CountryList {

    var ReturnOK: String?
    var Countryid: String?
    var Countryname: String?

    init(ReturnOK: String, Countryid: String, Countryname: String) {
        self.ReturnOK = ReturnOK
        self.Countryid = Countryid
        self.Countryname = Countryname
    }

    /*
     *  Fetch the country list
     */
    class func fetchCountryList() -> [CountryList] {

        var country_list = [CountryList]()

        // Add parameters
        let param: [String: String] = [
            Constants.LIST_COUNTRY.strAppID: Constants.OTHERS.temp_strAppID
        ]

            Alamofire.request(Constants.LIST_COUNTRY.URL, parameters:param, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { (response) in
                switch response.result {

                case .success(let value):
                    let json = JSON(value)

                    for (_, subJson):(String, JSON) in json {

                        let item = CountryList(
                            ReturnOK: subJson["ReturnOK"].stringValue,
                            Countryid: subJson["Countryid"].stringValue,
                            Countryname: subJson["Countryname"].stringValue)

                        country_list.append(item)
                    }

                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }

            }

        return country_list
    }

}
```

ViewController

```
class CreateAccountViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tf_country: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var picker_country: UIPickerView!

    var countryL: [CountryList]?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //  Get the country list
        countryL = CountryList.fetchCountryList()
        print(countryL)
    }

func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray {
            textView.text = nil
            textView.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        if textView.text.isEmpty {
            textView.text = "Address"
            textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }
    }

    //  Sets number of columns in picker view
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    //  Sets the number of rows in the picker view
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if let countryL = countryL {
            return countryL.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    //  This function sets the text of the picker view to the content of the "salutations" array
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        let titleRow = (countryL?[row] as? String)!
        return titleRow
    }

    // When user selects an option, this function will set the text of the text field to reflect
    // the selected option.
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if (countryL?.count)! > 0 && (countryL?.count)! >= 0 {
            self.tf_country.text = self.countryL?[row] as! String
            self.picker_country.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        //  When select th texfield, begin editing
        if (textField == self.tf_country) {
            self.picker_country.isHidden = false
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }
}
```

On Model I can see data is append. But when I print, it was nil.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

you should create a function with [Completion Handler](https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/)

idea here is that your `Alamofire` function is asynchronous, which means that, when you call `return country_list`, `Alamofire` request is not yet finished.

you should create a function with `handler` like

```
class func fetchCountries(handler: @escaping ([CountryList]) -> Void)) {
    //alamofire request here
    ...
    case .success(let value):
        let json = JSON(value)

        for (_, subJson):(String, JSON) in json {

            let item = CountryList(
                ReturnOK: subJson["ReturnOK"].stringValue,
                Countryid: subJson["Countryid"].stringValue,
                Countryname: subJson["Countryname"].stringValue)

             country_list.append(item)
         }
         handler(countryList) //this return countryList from this functions
}
```

and inside your `UIViewController` it will look like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //  Get the country list
    CountryList.fetchCountryList { [weak self] countryList in
        guard let `self` = self else { //this here to avoid reference cycle
          return
        }
        self.countryL = countryList
        //update your UI here
        print(countryL)
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, but what is this about `//this here to avoid reference cycle`. I dont understand.

Comment: @Dendi when you create a `CompletionHandler` you are creating a `closure`. In swift classes are `reference type`, this means, when you declare `var a = ClassA()` and then `var b = a`, you are creating 1 instance of `classA`, but `b` is referencing `a`. Cycle is, lets say `Class A` has reference to `Class B` and `Class B` has reference to `Class A`, so `ARC` will never destroy those objects. When you pass `UIViewController`, you create a `reference`, and when you call `closure`, `UIViewController` creates `reference` to the `closure`. That's why you have to `[weak self]`.

Comment: @Dendi you should just google `weak in Swift`, `Retain Cycles`, I would suggest to start with this http://www.thomashanning.com/retain-cycles-weak-unowned-swift/ . This is not actually really hard, a lot of examples with `Alamofire`

Comment: So the purpose is to block recreating the reference. On the other hand, in ViewController, why its starts execute the `delegate function` instead the func in `viewDidLoad` ?

Comment: yes, that is it. what do you mean by `delegate function`?

Comment: see the updates at question. When I debug, I noticed that, it will go through on entire `func` first, then only go to the viewDidLoad(). Why is that ?

Comment: that is how it works. just call `picker_country.reloadAllComponents()` inside `CompletionHandler`, after data loaded

Comment: Oh, needs to identify which IBOutlet need to be reload. What a silly of me. Dude, `let titleRow = (countryL?[row] as? String)!` this is wrong. How I can call the `Countryname` from the reference in swift ? Need to set a getter as well or not ?

Comment: @Dendi `countryL?[row].Countryname`, you should name your instance like `countryName` though

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. You really help me a lot. Do you have any blog or anything that enable us to keep in touch ?

Comment: @Dendi you can add me in telegram, I guess, that is the option. `juicyfru1t` nickname

Comment: Sure, but let me install the Telegram first :D